# Java Slider - how to make custom ticks?

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jslider

I have an audio track with an image slideshow - e.g. there's image 1 at 0:00, image 2 at 0:45, image 3 at 1:03 etc. I'm currently using a JSlider to change position in the track. I'd like to have ticks on the slider in the points where images change - but the spacing between ticks is not uniform, so `setPaintTicks` is not an option. Is there a way to do this with `javax.swing.JSlider`, or could you recommend a different slider control?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had this problem and didn't find a way to customise the tick spacing in JSlider.

You can use custom tick labels as a work-around, using **JSlider.setLabelTable()**. This allows you to label only certain ticks.